# Script to upload project automatically to github

Tags: git, github, upload

I've researched and found two repositories that look close to what I'm looking for, but having little to no understanding of the code inside them I need help, the script should work like that:

1. Running either from a terminal or a .exe inside a directory
2. Taking the name of the directory and create a repo with the same name inside my account
3. Execute basic commit and push of the files inside of the directory to the repository.

Sorry if I didn't explain myself correctly as this is my first question.

Thanks for you time.

Links to github repositories:

https://github.com/sagar-datta/auto-git-create

https://github.com/z33pX/Automated-GitHub-Repository-Creation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are my conclusions after a fast look into those repos:

- Those scripts can't update your remote repo (github repo) automatically after a change in your local repo.

and a brief about their approach:

1. Make a directory with the name you've said.
2. Make a github repo with that same name.
3. Make a `README.md` file and push some text into them.
4. Add and commit that `README.md`.
5. Make a remote with `origin` name, and with your github URL.
6. Push that `README.md` into your github repository.

So, Is this answer to your question?

Comment: Yes, thanks! That was exactly what i was looking for. I wasn't looking for changes to be uploaded. But i need help on two things: 1) Does the repo will have the files included in the directory? 2) How do i run the bash .sh one? Thanks for your time.

Comment: @DevLearner answer for **1)** No, It will just add `README.md` which itself made that before and don't try to add another file into your local repo because then you need to commit all of them before pushing into your remote repo  **2)** The bash file is for Linux I think, and I guess you are using Windows, So you should use another script (python one) for your job.