# continue for how to auto upload file to github disscussion

Tags: git, github, file-upload

continue for how to auto upload file to github disscussion
[Script to upload project automatically to github](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61565491/script-to-upload-project-automatically-to-github)

Is it saying that is impossible to automatically do that, like auto back up on every day 24:00 , saving the new code in new file?

Or there can be a way??

cause in that content seems we need to manually click on Github, open a new Repository and do the following everytime:

```
git init.
git add .
git commit -m "Add all my files"
git pull origin master.
git push origin master.
```

if above is the linux command to upload file, can we just run a script every midnight automatically upload code for us?

Then the new code we write just need to save in certain file, such like that.

Comment: You want a new repository each day or just push the changed files from last night to an existing repo?

Comment: Git is a version control system, not a backup system. A VCS can be pressed into service as a backup system, in the same way that a backup system can be pressed into service as a VCS, but the result will be <insert appropriately strong word for poor here>.

Comment: @jaspernygaard both, or at least one can save our effort, cause I don't wanna experience I write my own code and only save on local, even if just back up computer is not enough, so to answer ur question is looking for both way, or at least one on Github

Comment: Hi @torek, I meant not only for back up, like you write a new function, need to continue uploading each file for each function is kind of bothering, if every night we can set system to upload the new function in certain work file, I believe we can be more efficient

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to make sure that everything is committed by the end of the day, then schedule this script:

```
git pull && git add -A && git commit -m "Add all my files" && git push
```

If you want to initialize a new repostory each day, which I would discourage, then I would recommand you to use the GitHub CLI tool for creating the repo (or just just the REST API directly) and then schedule it with the following command

```
git push --mirror https://github.com/exampleuser/new-repository.git
```